# Scrollview and imageview

Tags: iphone, uitableview, textbox, uiscrollview, uiimageview

i add image view on scroll view. now i placed a buttons and textboxes on the imageview but when i scroll the view the text box and button are override with each other . or whther i used a tableview?

Comment: It's better to take a look at your code before answer the question

Comment: Also @er.mobileapp please learn to accept answers if they helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the frame of the textbox and buttons you have inserted. and check out whether you have added them on the imageview.

There may be other properties too that needs to be set.Needa check out...

Try with the above mentioned things.. If didnt work then you need to post the code of adding to the sub-view.

You have mentioned in the comment that you cannot post the code.
Here no one is asking you to post the entire project. Just post the part of code and if you think its violating then change the variable name and let us know the scenario for better help..

Comment: i simply add the imageview on scrollview.

Comment: And where are the buttons and text placed? Are u adding them as subview to imageview or scroll view?

Comment: i simply want to show the images on the scroll view there is no text box etc a

Comment: Please check out your question. and edit it as per your requirement so I can also edit my answer